# Symfony 2 - cant get the variable

Tags: php, symfony

this is my route

```
homepage:
    pattern: /{name}.{ext}
    defaults:
       _controller:  DprocMainBundle:Index:index
       name: index
       ext: php
    requirements:
       ext: php
       name: index
```

And i want to display {name} in my twig template. So the controller get the variable and sending it via array

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($index)
    {
        return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:index.html.twig', array('index' => $index));
    }
}
```

views

```
<title>{% block title %}Welcome - {{ name }}{% endblock %}</title>
```

There is error:

> Controller
>   "Dproc\MainBundle\Controller\IndexController::indexAction()" requires
>   that you provide a value for the "$index" argument (because there is
>   no default value or because there is a non optional argument after
>   this one).

Comment: change `$index` to `$name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller should be looked like this:

```
class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('DprocMainBundle:Dproc:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

You should change the name of variable - `$index` to `$name` because you declared it in the route. Moreover, you also used it in the Twig.